# Bézout theorem for complex solutions of systems of homogeneous quaternionic polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, quaternions, quaternionic-geometry, quaternion-algebras

Suppose that I have a system of $n$ homogeneous polynomials in $n+1$ variables $p_{1},\dots,p_{n}\in\mathbb{H}[x_{0},\dots,x_{n}]$ with coefficients at both sides in $\mathbb{H}.$ I want to know if there is an equivalent of the Bézout's theorem for determining if there exists a complex solution (that is, with $x_{0},\dots,x_{n}\in\mathbb{C}$) for the system that these polynomials form. An example of these polynomials with two sided quaternionic coefficients could be $p(x)=jx_{1}j-x_{1}x_{0}+ix_{0}i+kx_{0}$ and I am searching for criteria guaranteeing solutions of the form $a+bi\in\mathbb{C}$ (that is, with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$).